# Example Usage of the SuiteScript 2 error object

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

In the documentation, I don't see examples of the usage of SS 2 error objects. According to the docs, it looks considerably different. I would be thankful for the example of that usage.

Once again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple usage example of `N/error`:

```
if (!params.searchId) {
    log.error({title: "No Search provided", details: params});
    throw error.create({
        name: "ZC_INV_BREAKOUT_NO_SEARCH",
        message: "You must provide an appropriate Search for the Invoice Carveout script parameter."
    });
}
```

When a certain input isn't provided to this function, I throw an `Error` object using `N/error.create()`.

In this example, my module definition looks like:

```
define(["N/error", "N/log"], function (error, log) {
    ...
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for this and I appreciate it, one more question if I may. Does a catch statement still throw nlobjError or something similar? thanks